# Reverse diagonal on numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

let's say I have this:
(numpy array)

```
a=
[0  1  2  3],
[4  5  6  7],
[8  9 10  11]
```

to get [1,1] which is 5 its diagonal is zero; according to numpy, `a.diagonal(0)= [0,5,10]`. How do I get the reverse or the right to left diagonal [2,5,8] for [1,1]? Is this possible?
My original problem is an 8 by 8 (0:7).. I hope that helps

Comment: there are two answers that appear not generalized enough becuase your sample a is small.  Do you want the answer for [2,2] to be [7, 10]? related question, can you be rectangular in the other direction (tall not wide)?

Comment: My example is an 8 by 8 (0:7).. I hope that helps

Answer (score 17):

Get a new array each row reversed.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([
...     [0, 1, 2, 3],
...     [4, 5, 6, 7],
...     [8, 9, 10, 11]
... ])
>>> a[:, ::-1]
array([[ 3,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  5,  4],
       [11, 10,  9,  8]])
>>> a[:, ::-1].diagonal(1)
array([2, 5, 8])
```

or using [`numpy.fliplr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html):

```
>>> np.fliplr(a).diagonal(1)
array([2, 5, 8])
```

Comment: Note for the general case this requires calculating the offset from the other side of the array, e.g. you will need to use `a.shape` in your calculations

Comment: @wim, You're right. Your answer is more elegant in regard to this matter. Thank you for comment. +1

Comment: In my program, I dont get to know the "1" inside the diagonal function? How do I get that?

Comment: @AhmedNassar, You can use `max(a.shape[1]-a.shape[0], 0)` instead of `1`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused how can I use this.  i might've not been clear, let's say I want to get [3,6,9] what operation should I take to get it straight away, without looking at the table.

Comment: @AhmedNassar, Try `a[:, ::-1].diagonal(0)` or `np.fliplr(a).diagonal(0)`.

Answer (score 5):

Flip the array upside-down and use the same:

```
np.flipud(a).diagonal(0)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve this is to use `np.rot90`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,  1,  2,  3],
              [4,  5,  6,  7],
              [8,  9, 10,  11]])            

my_diag = np.rot90(a).diagonal(-1)
```

Result:

```
>>> my_diag
array([2, 5, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of answers so far.  @Akavall is closest as you need to rotate or filip and transpose (equivilant operations).  I haven't seen a response from the OP regarding expected behavior on the "long" part of the rectangle.

Generalized solution for a square matrix:

```
a = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
           [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> [(i, np.rot90(a).diagonal(2*i-a.shape[0]+1)) for i in range(a.shape[0])]
[(0, array([0])),
 (1, array([ 2,  6, 10])),
 (2, array([ 4,  8, 12, 16, 20])),
 (3, array([14, 18, 22])),
 (4, array([24]))]
```

As a function:

```
def reverse_diag(arr, n):
    idx = 2*n - arr.shape[0]+1
    return np.rot90(arr).diagonal(idx)
```

original matrix can be made square with `a[:np.min(a.shape),:np.min(a.shape)]`

**EDIT**: OP indicated the array is square.... **Final Answer** is the above